# ngControl cannot get default values in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm creating form using Angular 2 (RC.3), but `ngForm` directive cannot get default values ( `value` attribute ).

```
// app.component.html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editForm.value)" #editForm="ngForm">
  <input ngControl="firstName" type="text" value="{{user?.firstName}}">
  <input ngControl="lastName" type="text" value="{{user?.lastName}}">

  <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>

// app.component.ts
...
export class AppComponent {
  public user: UserModel;

  constructor(private _api: ApiService) {
    // Get user data.
    this._api.get('/users/self').subscribe(
      (user: UserModel): void => { this.user = user; }
    );
  }
  onSubmit(user: UserModel): void {
    console.log(user);
  }
}
```

If `user` object has the user data, `input` element is set a value of `firstName` user object has. When I do not input and not change `input` element's values (i.e. using `value` attribute values), `editForm.value` has no values like the below.

```
{ firstName: null, lastName: null }
```

When I change `input` element's values, `editForm.value` detects its changes and be set values.
What should I do?

---

Also, I don't understand how to use `ngControl` and `ngModel` properly. I know `ngControl` provides validations and operation statuses, `ngModel` provides to sync presentation layer models, but I don't understand the difference between `ngControl` and `ngModel` completely.

I think that we can get form values using only `ngControl`, so `ngModel` and two way binding is not needed...

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms-deprecated.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form-deprecated.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your component:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from "@angular/common";
import { ApiService } from "./services/api-service";
import { UserModel } from "./models/user-model";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    providers: [ApiService],
})
export class PlayerPage {

    user: UserModel;
    userForm: ControlGroup;

    constructor(private _api: ApiService, fb: FormBuilder) {

        // initialize to a new, blank user
        this.user = new UserModel();

        // get the user
        this._api.get("users/self").subscribe((user: UserModel): void => {
            this.user = user;
        });

        // create a control group for the form
        this.userForm = fb.group({
            firstName: [this.user.firstName, Validators.required],
            lastName:  [this.user.lastName,  Validators.required]
        });
    }

    onSubmit($event, user) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        console.log(user);
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
// app.component.html
<form [ngFormModel]="userForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event, user)">
    <input ngControl="firstName" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" />
    <input ngControl="lastName"  [(ngModel)]="user.lastName"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid" />
</form>
```

One problem might be that the API call doesn't return in a timely fashion and so there's no data to populate your form with. Otherwise, the submit button on this form will be disabled while the form is invalid, in this case, if either of the two fields is blank.